# accessing a variable showing in single line instead of multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am storing the multiple lines in a variable and when I am trying to access them it is showing in a single line.

```
$ echo -e "A\nB"
A
B
$ VAR=`echo -e "A\nB"`
$ echo $VAR
A B
```

let me know is there any way to get the output as same as command. I want A, B to be in different lines while accessing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need quotes when echoing:

```
$ var=$(echo -e "A\nB")

$ echo "$var"
A
B
```

Comment: The double quotes prevent [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)

Answer (score 0):

$ VAR=`echo -e "A\nB"`
$ echo "$VAR"
A 
B